# How I can purchase a Google Play product item multiple times?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, developer-console

I can buy only one item ("productitem1"). If I had purchase this item, I can't purchase it again. But I need it to buy it several times. In my Google Play Console, I can only choose between "Managed In-app Products" and "subs". I have setting it up to "Managed In-app Products".

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    if (request == 42) {
        int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
        String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATE_SIGNATURE");
        if (response == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String productId = jo.getString("productId");
                Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "JSONException", e);
            }
        }
    }
}

btnBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String name = "productitem1";
            try {
                Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), name, "inapp", "");
                if(buyIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE")==0) {
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                            pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 42, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Start.this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"Exception:",e);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you can buy another item with the same SKU, you need to consume it using one of the methods available from the In-App Billing API like `IabHelper.consumeAsync()`

```
mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_ITEM), mConsumeFinishedListener);

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
           new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // provision the in-app purchase to the user
            // (for example, credit 50 gold coins to player's character)
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
    }
};
```

More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Consume

Comment: I get the errors: Cannot resolve symbol 'mHelper' and Cannot resolve symbol 'IabHelper'

Comment: How are you purchasing items? Please add some more code to your question se we can see which version of the purchase library you are using (Obviously mHelper is a `IabHelper` instance)

Comment: I purchase items with the code in my question post. I have imported the actually files from google. All purchases work fine, but I can purchase all items only one time, not multiple.

Comment: If I add your code, I get the error Cannot resolve symbol 'mHelper' and Cannot resolve symbol 'IabHelper'

Comment: Anything to import that I can use the IabHelper and mHelper ? I have imported "import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;"

Comment: Post the link of the sample you imported in your project for IAP flow

Comment: I use the android SDK, downloading the Google Play Billing Library (version 5), an import the 9 java files into my project (SDK/extras/google/play_billing/samples/TrivialDrive/src/com/xample/android/trivialdrivesample/util)

Comment: If you added all the classes, you will see that at [this link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util) you have 8 classes to add to your project, one of them is `IabHelper` then you need to handle all the purchase procedure using a private var mHelper in your code [like the example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/MainActivity.java#L139) in the MainActivity class

Comment: I've added the code below in my answer-post. But I get the Errors "Variable 'mHelper' might not have been initialized

Comment: Man you need to initialize the property first... if you search for "mHelper" string in the MainActivity.class i linked you in the previous comment you will see that at some point the property [is initialized](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/MainActivity.java#L177), i will suggest you to make some base understanding of object oriented programming before proceding on in-app purchases flow because your are probably lacking in it. Good luck :)

Comment: thank you, but now I get a new error :-( Look at my edited answer post...

Answer (score 0):

```
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener onConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
            try {
                Log.d("Tag", "this is onConsumeFinished - "+result.toString()+" and purchased"+purchase.toString());
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase,onConsumeFinishedListener);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {

                Log.d("Tag", "this is onConsumeFinished Error -  "+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).